# NA/NaN argument error when using raster:stack function

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a raster with depth and I need to create a raster from it for incline and then stack the two rasters into a RasterStack. However I get this error:

> Error in raster:stack(env, incline_rast) : NA/NaN argument

Here is my code:

```
#create incline raster from depth raster that is called env
incline_rast<-terrain(env,opt="slope")

## creating raster stack

stack <- raster:stack(env, incline_rast)
Error in raster:stack(env, incline_rast) : NA/NaN argument


stack <- raster:stack(env, incline_rast, quick = TRUE)
Error in raster:stack(env, incline_rast) : NA/NaN argument
```

The rasters have the same extent and coordinate system. What does this error mean and how to fix it? As I ma using R code to create one raster from another, why would it gve me an error?

How can I add information about the raster to make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `raster::stack(env,incline_raster)`.

You are using the single colon in a wrong context:

A single colon `:` is used to generate sequences, for example:

```
> 1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Whereas a double or triple colon `::`& `:::` is used to access exported and internal variables:

```
package::function
```

For more information have a look [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Colon.html) or [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html).

Simply load the package beforehand with `library(raster)` or use the double colon `::` notation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped